# Scala comprehension from input

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I am having troubles constructing a Map from inputs.

Here is my problem :

I am getting an input for elevators information. It consists of **n** lines, each one has the **elevatorFloor** number and the **elevatorPosition** on the floor.

Example:

```
0 5
1 3
4 5
```

So here I have 3 elevators, first one is on floor 0 at position 5, second one at floor 1 position 3 etc..

Is there a way in Scala to put it in a Map without using var ?

What I get so far is a Vector of all the elevators' information :

```
val elevators = {
    for{i <- 0 until n
        j <- readLine split " "
    } yield j.toInt
}
```

I would like to be able split the lines in two variables "elevatorFloor" and "elevatorPos" and group them in a data structure (my guess is Map would be the appropriate choice) I would like to get something looking like:

```
elevators: SomeDataStructure[Int,Int] = ( 0->5, 1 -> 3, 4 -> 5)
```

I would like to clarify that I know I could write Javaish code, initialise a Map and then add the values to it, but I am trying to keep as close to functionnal programming as possible.

Thanks for the help or comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
val res: Map[Int, Int] = 
  Source.fromFile("myfile.txt")
        .getLines
        .map { line => 
          Array(floor, position) = line.split(' ')
          (floor.toInt -> position.toInt)
        }.toMap
```

Comment: What if the file is passed as a stream (in competitive coding it happens) : myscala.scala < input.txt  ? Can I get multiple lines as well ?

Comment: Sure: ``Source.stdin.getLines``